# How to configure ng-semantic in latest angular2 release candidate?

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I'm trying to configure ng-semantic with angular2 release candidate 4 but so far haven't been successful. Been following the instructions on the main npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-semantic)

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around for awhile I finally got it to work. Note that I'm using ng-semantic 1.0.32 and angular 2 rc4.

### Step 1:

You need to add ng-semantic to the `vendorNPMFiles` array in angular-cli-build.js
When you run `ng build`, `ng serve` or `ng start` the angular cli builds your project and outputs to the dist folder which has a vendor directory. This vendor directory contains the packages listed in `vendorNPMFiles`. Any package added in `vendorNPMFiles` has to already exist in the `node_modules` directory. So you should add ng-semantic like this:

```
[
  .....,
  'ng-semantic/**/*'
]
```

### Step 2:

You need to configure ng-semantic in `src/system-config.ts`. So first you'll need to add it to the map object like this:

```
const map: any = {
  'ng-semantic': 'vendor/ng-semantic',
}
```

Then you'll also need to add it in the packages object like this:

```
const packages: any = { 
  'ng-semantic': {main:'ng-semantic.js', defaultExtension:'js'}
}
```

### Finally

After that you should be able to use it in any component like this:

```ts
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import { SEMANTIC_COMPONENTS, SEMANTIC_DIRECTIVES } from "ng-semantic";

    @Component({
      selector: 'demo-cmp',
      directives: [SEMANTIC_COMPONENTS, SEMANTIC_DIRECTIVES],
      template: `
        <sm-segment class="raised">
         Hello
        </sm-segment>
      `
    })
    export class DemoComponent {}
```